# How to write data to "sales_flat_order_payment" table in a custom field?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

In my custom module, I changed the table `sales_flat_order_payment` and `sales_flat_quote_payment` and added two new fields:

```
$installer->run("
  ALTER TABLE `{$installer->getTable('sales/quote_payment')}` ADD `ep_entity` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ;
  ALTER TABLE `{$installer->getTable('sales/quote_payment')}` ADD `ep_reference` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ;

  ALTER TABLE `{$installer->getTable('sales/order_payment')}` ADD `ep_entity` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ;
  ALTER TABLE `{$installer->getTable('sales/order_payment')}` ADD `ep_reference` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ;
");
```

In my model , there is the following function that will make the client redirect to my custom success page:

```
public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl() {
    return Mage::getUrl('mymodule/mymethod/success', array('_secure' => false));
}
```

In the controller, there is the following function:

```
public function successAction()
{
    $incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
    $order->setEpReference('123456');
    $order->save(); 
}
```

The problem is that no data is recorded on the `sales_flat_order_payment` table in the `ep_reference` field.

How to write data to `sales_flat_order_payment` table in a custom field?

I don't want to add custom fields in the form, the custom field is automatically populated after the payment is completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
public function successAction()
{
    $incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

    $payment = $order->getPayment();
    $payment->setEpReference('123456');

    $paymentQuote = $quote->getPayment();
    $paymentQuote->setEpReference('123456');
    $paymentQuote->save();

    $order->save(); 
}
```